# How to access time picker buttons?

Tags: android

I seen on other fourms on how you can access the cancel button on time picker by using  .OnDismissListener but there notting on how to access the set button of a timepicker how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the TimePicker Android tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html).

You add a `OnTimeSetListener`, which is called when the set button is called.

For example (from the tutorial):

```
// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i had it kind of implemented it works now thanks :)